# Issue with react component cache

Tags: reactjs

I have such a simple example https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-boolean-basic-example-forked-plrfny. You will notice that clicking on button `0` and `1` will both print `True`. However the intention is to print `True` when click `0` and `False` when click `1`. It looks like when clicking `1`, a `Test` component is created with the same initial props as when clicking `0`. The solution is to add a `key` property. Any idea why they use the same initial props?

Comment: The reason is Test component recieves 'init' variable as the prop as true or false but that variable is not the prop of the output in Test component but a default placeholder for its own useState. Get rid of the useState for Test component and just use the prop 'init' to drive its output.

Comment: useState is intentional as my actual component need to modify state after being initialized with props. The question still remain, why in the second Test component, the state is not initialized with the corresponding prop, but instead it use the first  Test component state